# Solving for add./sub. equation with same exponents, different bases

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function, exponentiation

The exponent term is the same, while the bases are different. Can I simplify this for an addition/subtraction equation?

$$2^{(1-r)} + 9(1.6^{(1-r)}) - 3.85^{(1-r)} - 9(0.1^{(1-r)}) = 0 $$

Comment: You have to have the same bases to be able to simplify. First, substitute $x=1-r$ to simplify the powers. Then replace each term of the form $a^x$ with $e^{x\ln(a)}$, which gives you the same base, which is important. Can you take it from there?

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! I'll work on it from there.